# How to tell whether screen saver is running in a Qt (C/C++) program? (MS Windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt, command-line

I tried to get the output of tasklist when screen saver is running to see if a specific process is running when screen saver is active, but I couldn't get the output of tasklist in my program.

I tried using Qt's QProcess and C's system function, but running tasklist failed in both of them (no output). I don't know the reason!

Even running something like system("tasklist > out.txt") creates an empty out.txt file!

Anyway I am seeking the simplest way to tell if screen saver is running in a C/C++/Qt program.

I am using Windows XP sp3.

Comment: I think you can identify screensavers by it's window class name. "WindowsScreenSaverClass" 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144066(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself!

First, tasklist.exe didn't work because I invoked my program from the Qt command prompt and the Qt command prompt sets its own PATH environment variable. tasklist.exe needs a dll named framedyn.dll that isn't in the Qt command prompt's PATH (I found it in C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem).

Second, to tell if screen saver is running, first I used searching for '.scr' in the output of the tasklist, but finally found (someone suggested) a seemingly much better way:

```
bool bSaver;
SystemParametersInfo(114,0,&bSaver,0);
if(bSaver) QMessageBox::information(0, "hi", "screen saver is running");
else QMessageBox::information(0, "hi", "screen saver is not running");
```

Note: to use this code you need to add `#include <windows.h>` to your Qt source file.

Comment: You should probably use `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING` rather than `114` and also pass the address of a `BOOL`, which is a typedef for `int`, rather than `bool` which is generally not the same size.

Comment: I used 114 because with SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING I get 'undeclared' error even though I included 'winuser.h' too. I am using MinGW for compiling.

Comment: You need to set `WIN_VER` >= 0x500 in order for it to be defined.  You can see that in WinUser.h

Comment: yes i also noticed it but i didn't think that it must be set manually! seems a little weird.